# How to suppress stdout 'batch' when streaming spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka

How to change or totally supress this batch metadata and only show my thing?

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 62
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
| key|value|      topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+----+-----+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|null| [32]|transaction|        0|335793|2020-07-27 15:10:...|            0|
+----+-----+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 63
-------------------------------------------
+----+-----+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
| key|value|      topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+----+-----+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|null| [33]|transaction|        0|335794|2020-07-27 15:10:...|            0|
+----+-----+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+

-------------------------------------------
```

the spark_job.py code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import time
KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "transaction"
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS = '127.0.0.1:9092'
project_path = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/kafka_project'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka Demo Application Started ...")

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka Demo") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .config("spark.jars",                    "file:///C://Users//Admin//Desktop//kafka_project//spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.6.jar,file:///C://Users//Admin//Desktop//kafka_project//kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar") \
        .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "file:///C://Users//Admin//Desktop//kafka_project//spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.6.jar,file:///C://Users//Admin//Desktop//kafka_project//kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar") \
        .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary",   "file:///C://Users//Admin//Desktop//kafka_project//spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.6.jar,file:///C://Users//Admin//Desktop//kafka_project//kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar") \
        .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath",   "file:///C://Users//Admin//Desktop//kafka_project//spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.6.jar,file:///C://Users//Admin//Desktop//kafka_project//kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar") \
        .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    incoming_read = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS) \
        .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS)\
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
        .load()

    query1 = incoming_read.writeStream.format("console").start()
    time.sleep(4)


    query1.awaitTermination()
    incoming_read.awaitTermination()
    
    
    print("PySpark demo app finished.")
```

the producer.py forever sends numbers 0 to 7 with interval 4 seconds:

```
# coding=utf8
from time import sleep
from json import dumps
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['127.0.0.1:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x: 
                         dumps(x).encode('utf-8')
                         )

topic = 'transaction'

while True:
    print('restarting the loop...')
    for i in range(7):
        print('producing for this topic %s this blob: %s ' % (topic,i))

        producer.send(topic, value=i)
        sleep(1)
```

Also, how to actually see the last line 'pyspark demo app finished'?

Do i need to stop producer and just wait when spark.py  timeouts?
using spark2.4.6,python3.7

Comment: Hi @ERJAN, does below answer answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/sources/ConsoleWrite.scala#L47) of the class `ConsoleWrite` it is not possible to suppress or change the "Batch" output when using the Console output as it seems to be hard coded.:

```scala
override def commit(epochId: Long, messages: Array[WriterCommitMessage]): Unit = {
    // We have to print a "Batch" label for the epoch for compatibility 
    // with the pre-data source V2 behavior.
    printRows(messages, schema, s"Batch: $epochId")
  }

  protected def printRows(
      commitMessages: Array[WriterCommitMessage],
      schema: StructType,
      printMessage: String): Unit = {
[...]
    // scalastyle:off println
    println("-------------------------------------------")
    println(printMessage)
    println("-------------------------------------------")
    // scalastyle:off println
[...]
  }
```

Unless there is a way to suppress `println` statements.

> Also, how to actually see the last line 'pyspark demo app finished'?

You need to terminate your application by either sending a SIGTERM signal or just kill your submitted application. Not sure though if you will be able to see your print statement in the very last line of your code. The producer has nothing to do with this.